# What information is needed when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Depending on what the question is about, there are certain things that the people who are going to answer the question will need to know first. Including this information should help skip over the banter of people asking for more information, and get right into people giving you an answer.

- What do I need to include in a question asking for medical advice?
- What do I need to include in a question asking about changes in my
  pet's behaviour?
- What do I need to include in a question asking for training advice?